# Prepared statements in java

Tags: java, performance, jdbc, memcached

I have a use case where I use memcache to cache certain results from DB. I use the query itself as the key and value will be of type `CachedRowSetImpl` which serializes the result set. To form the query, I need to use `PreparedStatement` which in turn needs a connection object to the DB. This defeats the whole purpose of caching since more than half the time is being spent in establishing the connection. Is there any work around for this? Or do I have to use an alternate approach to cache results?

Comment: How are you obtaining the connection, via Connection Pool or creating the connection manually?

Comment: Well, now you have found the culprit of opening your connections being slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid establishing a connection every time, you use a connection pool, like [c3p0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0). You configure a connection pool to use Postgres, username swaldman, and passwordComboPooledDataSource

```
// in constructor
cpds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
cpds.setDriverClass( "org.postgresql.Driver" ); //loads the jdbc driver            
cpds.setJdbcUrl( "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/testdb" );
cpds.setUser("swaldman");                                  
cpds.setPassword("test-password");
```

When you need a JDBC Connection, just use:

```
Connection connection = cpds.getConnection();
```

There are other connection pools, like [DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp), which are set up in a similar way.